# WEKA accuracy confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, population, weka, accuracy

I have a dataset consisting of thousands of companies from the UK.
For 300 of these companies, I collected several indicators which were extracted from social media (e.g. #likes).
I have built a model using the WEKA data mining tool that achieves an accuracy of approximately 70%.
I am trying to statistically underpin if this accuracy is significant.

I wanted to compute the confidence interval of this accuracy.
The sample size in my case is 300.
However, if I am correct, it also requires you to know the population size.

1. What in my case would be the population? Is that all UK companies, or the thousands of UK companies for which I got a rating, or something else?
2. In this case, if I want to determine the accuracy with 95% confidence, what do I need to fill in for $p$ and $e$ in the following formula:

$n=\frac{z^{2}(pq)}{c^{2}}$

n=sample_size; z=sample_error belonging to confidence interval (1.96 for 95%); p=estimated percentage of the population; q=100-p; e=acceptable sample error;

3. Do you have any other suggestions for underpinning these results statistically?

Comment: The population is the set of things about which you want to draw inferences--something you haven't yet disclosed. Of more import may be *how* you collected indicators. If your sample of companies consists exactly of those for which you found one or more "likes" in social media, then your sample is extremely far from being random or representative. Even inferences made about those 300 companies alone might be suspect, depending on what you are trying to infer.

Comment: I also included the companies for which no indicator could be found, by adding them with a 0 value. Would the population then be all UK companies, since I want to determine whether information from social media can be used to predict the credtiworthiness of those companies? Would another possibility for statistically underpinning these result be determine how much better it performs than random assigning companies one of the rating classes? If I am correct, the Student's t-distribution can be used for that?